# SVG grid (pattern) misbehaves in Firefox

Tags: html, svg, cross-browser

I'm implementing a grid of a fixed number of 'units' that adapts (is fitted) to the width of its container. So in order for the number of grid-units to remain constant, the grid-unit width is variable and is appropriately modified whenever the width of the container changes.

As a solution for this, I'm using an SVG pattern:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="grid" width="{size}" height="{size}" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <path d="M {size} 0 L 0 0 0 {size}" fill="none" stroke="#BBB" stroke-width="1"/>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grid)" />
</svg>
```

where `{size}` is dynamically set according to the container width. Here's the [relevant fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S9Fbv/9/) (note that the height of the container is not important in this case - only the width is).

As can be seen from the fiddle, this works fine on Chrome but is problematic on Firefox [v29.0.1, for the Mac] as the grid will generally not properly fit into the container. As the width of the latter changes, the grid always seems to be off by a few pixels, as if there's some rounding error involved.

Can this be fixed somehow, so that it works as expected across (modern) browsers?

Please note that my understanding of SVGs is pretty limited - honestly, the bit above was basically copy-pasted and tweaked to fit the purpose. If someone could point me to relevant documentation or even suggest an altogether different method of achieving the same result, that would be very helpful.

[update: This seems to be specific to the *Mac version* of FF]

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://cs.sru.edu/~ddailey/svg/grid.svg 
There are two different strategies used there.
On left, I used your approach -- a path drawn inside a pattern that is then applied to a rect.
In order to make it rescale, I used a viewBox to declare the coordinate system employed. This is because "path" works in absolute coordinates rather than percentages of the screen size.
The second on right, just uses two lines inside the pattern, since lines can be drawn using percentages. 
The preserveAspectRatio thing may not be desirable since it allows the aspect ratio to change, hence the grid might not remain square. But it does have the advantage of rescaling to any screen. Am not sure if the culture at stackoverflow prefers source code or links to examples but the example is pretty brief.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Your examples will be very useful as reference but unfortunately they exhibit the same problematic behaviour on FF/Mac. If you take a look at the page on such a setup you'll notice that the grid doesn't resize smoothly/accurately but rather behaves as if 'snapping' to specific widths.

Comment: I don't have access to FF Mac, but it sounds like a bug therein. It works fine in FF, IE, Opera and Chrome under windows, though there is some funky jerkiness on resizing of the sort you describe in Safari (which is now defunct in Windows) . Maybe consider reporting it through Bugzilla. unfortunately, these days, most browsers require one to register to report bugs.